# Why won't CSS properties and media queries work on certain elements

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, browser, developer-tools

I am trying to build a portfolio page with React and using SCSS to style.
I am not completely new to these libraries as I have been using them both for a while now. Recently, I have encountered some problems with the styles on certain elements not reflecting on the browser.

I have an header element with a nested nav element. The styling worked fine until I tried to change the "color" property of the h4 and 'li' elements. Nothing worked. My code is fine as there are no errors on the SCSS page. I have also tried to use different browsers and cleared my caches still nothing changed. It is getting quite frustrating as this isn't letting me progress with my work.

//Here is the react code

```html
export default function Header() {
    return (
        <>
        <header>
            <nav>
                <h4 className="color">
                    <NavLink to='/'>Chidera</NavLink>
                </h4>

                <ul class="nav-links">
                    <li><NavLink to='/'> Home</NavLink></li>
                    <li><NavLink to='portfolio'> Portfolio</NavLink></li>
                    
                </ul>

                <div class="burger">
                    <div class="line1"></div>
                    <div class="line2"></div>
                    <div class="line3"></div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <Outlet/>
        </>
    )
}
```

//SCSS code

```css
 header {
        width: 100%;
        height: 10vh;
        display: grid;
        place-items: center;

        nav {
            width: 80%;
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;

            h4 {
                font-size: 1.2rem;
                color: gold;
                font-style: italic;
                background-color: #48ff00;
            }

            ul {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: space-between;
                align-items: center;
                width: 40%;
                color: white;
                padding: 0 1rem;

                li {
                    color: white;
                    background-color: #1906cc;
                }
            }

            .burger {
                cursor: pointer;
                display: none;

                div {
                    width: 25px;
                    height: 3px;
                    background-color: rgb(221, 168, 90);
                    margin: 5px;
                    transition: all 0.3s ease;
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
```

I have also noticed that the media queries aren't working on certain elements as well. Again, this is not an issue with my code as there are no error messages on SCSS regarding this. For instance, I want my burger element to display when the device is below 800px. Setting burger to display: block; did absolutely nothing but I was able to change the background color of the main element. I don't know if this is an issue with the SCSS cause even if I nest the elements the same way they appear on the react page, nothing works still.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    main {
        background-color: pink; //works
    }
    .burger {
        display: block; //does nothing
    }
}
```

[image: Elements' colors do not change]

[image: Query selector issue]

Notice how the developer's tools acknowledges the color property in the second image but nothing reflects on the page itself. Also see how the main background color changes to pink but the burger does not display.

I hope this is not an issue with SCSS cause I am too lazy to go back to plain css

Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**NavLink and Link from 'react-router-dom'** have their default property. CSS property of h4 and li won't override the NavLink and Link property. You need to directly override the property of NavLink and Link.

The first step, take out the color from the h4 and li

```
 <h4 className="color">
     <NavLink to="/" className="colorGold">Chidera</NavLink>
 </h4>
```

CSS

```
.colorGold {
  color: gold;
}
```

li part property

```
<ul className="nav-links">
      <li>
           <NavLink to="/" className="listColor">Home</NavLink>
      </li>
      <li>
           <NavLink to="/portfolio" className="listColor">Portfolio</NavLink>
      </li>
</ul>
```

css

```
.listColor {
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: OMG. Thank you so so much. I did as you wrote and it styles fine now. However, instead of adding a className to the navlink, I did this 'a {color: white;}' on the scss. Thank so much